# How to choose a valid VIP for kube-vip HA Cluster setup?

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-ip

I am following this reference https://kube-vip.io/control-plane/ for HA cluster setup.
I want to setup 3 master - 1 worker cluster for testing purpose.

The documentation uses 192.168.0.75 as VIP, but not mentioning how they got this IP

As I am using digitalocean droplets for Kubernetes, I tried using IP from VPC IP range, say it is 10.x.y.z for `kubeadm init` which is same for all the droplets. But, I am not able to do `kubeadm join` with this IP (says. http://10.x.y.z:6443 no route to host)

How do I get a valid VIP value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kube-vip itself does not really care what IP address you use, as long as it is 'free' and in the same subnet your chosen interface is in.

Suppose eth0 on the master nodes looks like this:

```
// master node 1
eth0 inet addr:192.168.1.11
     bcast:192.168.1.255
     mask:255.255.255.0

// master node 2
eth0 inet addr:192.168.1.12
     bcast:192.168.1.255
     mask:255.255.255.0

// master node 3
eth0 inet addr:192.168.1.13
     bcast:192.168.1.255
     mask:255.255.255.0
```

You can now use `192.168.1.X` as the VIP. `192.168.1.67` would work, and so would `192.168.1.182` or `192.168.1.10` (assuming the addresses are 'free'). None of these IP addresses is 'more valid' than the others.

I am not sure how all of this works on digitalocean (since I have never used it), but you will probably have to assign an additional IP address that all nodes can use. On linode (similar platform) for example, there is an option called 'IP sharing', which allows you to share one IP between multiple nodes.

But all that aside, you probably do not even need kube-vip, as [digitalocean offers managed TCP load balancers](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/load-balancers/) which is probably what you are looking for. I have even found [a tutorial on how to set up an HA control plane with digitalocean's managed load balancer](https://web.archive.org/web/20220119123342/https://www.suse.com/c/rancher_blog/set-up-your-k3s-cluster-for-high-availability-on-digitalocean/).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Eleasar's answer.
I can add on that you're receiving `http://10.x.y.z:6443 no route to host` because you must use `kubeadm join` with *master node IP* and **not** *Kube-VIP IP*.